# Reading CSV using R where header is on the second line

Tags: r, csv

I know that in R I can read in a csv file using `read.csv`. I also know that by setting `header = TRUE` I can indicate to R that there is a header with variable names on the first row.

However, I am trying to read in a csv that places a timestamp on the first row and the header / variable names on the second.  I can obviously manually strip off the first line before loading it into R, but it’s a pain to do this each time.  Is there an elegant solution to this in R?

Comment: `?read.table`, argument `skip`.

Comment: you can use `skip=1` argument to skip the first row and set `header=TRUE` as usual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `skip` argument to `read.csv`

```
read.csv(.... , skip=1)
```

Comment: That works; thank you.  I was under the impression that skip would skip the first row of data.  I guess I should have tested that theory.

Answer (score 3):

For the subjective "elegant", you may want to look at `fread` from "data.table" which generally does a good job of figuring out where the data actually start.

An example:

#### Create a fake CSV file in our workspace

The first line has "something" and the actual data starts on the second line with the headers "V1", "V2", and "V3".

```
x <- tempfile()
cat("something",
    "V1,V2,V3",
    "1,2,3", "4,5,6", "7,8,9", sep = "\n", file = x)
```

#### Load "data.table" and try `fread`

Seems to work out of the box! Obviously replace `x` with the name of your actual CSV file.

```
library(data.table)
fread(x)
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  1  2  3
# 2:  4  5  6
# 3:  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thanks you for this.  I think the previously posted skip will work for now, but I will definitely tuck this away for future use.

Comment: @Chris, no problem. Just FYI, `fread` is *FAST*, so if you're working with large CSV files, you should definitely check it out sooner rather than later....